# Does the Nikon D600 have a lockable mode wheel?

Tags: nikon, camera-controls, nikon-d600

At the moment I am using a D7000 for portrait shoots but for some reason I keen on knocking the mode wheel from A to M quite often and it results in over or underexposed shots.

I see that on top of the D600 mode where there is a small button, is that a push and select, like the ring that is below it?

Also do any of the other Nikon full frame bodies have a lockable selector?

Comment: One of the biggest weaknesses of the Canon 7D and 5DII, later top tier Canon bodies with a mode dial have a lockable one. You can also send your 7D or 5DII to Canon Factory Service and get a lockable one retrofitted (for a fee).

Comment: Yeah I heard about that. I might have to see if I can think of a way to hold the wheel in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the D600 does have a lockable mode wheel.

> On the upper left of the D600's body (when the camera is viewed from behind) you'll find a D7000-style exposure mode dial and around its base, another dial for shooting modes. Both dials are lockable, which prevents accidental operation.

From [the DPReview review](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/nikon-d600/5).

The D600 and D610 are the only full frame Nikon DSLRs with mode wheels, lockable or otherwise. The D800, D3 and D4 all use a push button and wheel combination to switch between P, S, A and M modes.

Comment: Fantastic. The D7000 mode wheel is pushing me towards a new camera at the moment, as it is causing me so many problems.